# SQL Server 2008 : PASS matching records

Tags: sql, matching, records

`TableA` (`id int, batch char(15), mode char(10), match2 char(15), status char(15)`)

```
ID Match  MODE  match2 STATUS
1  ABC12   A     123
2  ABC12   A     123
3  ABC12   A     123
4  ABC12   B     234
5  ABC12   B     234
6  BCD32   A     456
7  BCD32   B     456
```

So, I need to populate Status with 'PASS' where mode = 'B' and

1. For same match, if its corresponding mode A (ID1,2,3) if we talk about ABC12, It has different Match2.

So ID 4 and 5 will get "PASS".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if B matches any A record on the "MATCH", and not on the match2 attribute, then that B record is a PASS?  Is this sql server or mysql or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (id int, match char(15), mode char(10),match2 char(15), status char(15))


INSERT INTO TableA (ID, Match,  MODE,  match2)
SELECT 1,  'ABC12',   'A',     123 UNION
SELECT 2,  'ABC12',   'A',     123 UNION
SELECT 3,  'ABC12',   'A',     123 UNION
SELECT 4,  'ABC12',   'B',     234 UNION
SELECT 5,  'ABC12',   'B',     234 UNION
SELECT 6,  'BCD32',   'A',     456 UNION
SELECT 7,  'BCD32',   'B',     456 UNION
SELECT 8,  'ABC23',   'A',     NULL UNION
SELECT 9,  'ABC23',   'B',     789


UPDATE
    t1
SET
    status = 'PASS'
FROM
    TableA AS t1
JOIN
    TableA AS t2
ON
    t1.id != t2.id
AND t1.match = t2.match
AND (t1.match2 != t2.match2 OR t2.match2 IS NULL)
AND t2.mode = 'A'
WHERE
    t1.mode = 'B'

SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Comment: What if match2= null for mode=A and match=abc12. Its should still pass ID 4 and 5 but here it won't coz we are comparing NULL to a value . Please edit. Thanks

Comment: I added another case (see IDs 8 and 9) - is that what you meant? The code above will mark 9 as `PASS` as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate, using diaho's TableA

```
MERGE TableA
  USING (SELECT match, mode, match2 from TableA 
            GROUP BY match, mode, match2) as matches 
ON Tablea.mode = 'B' and matches.mode = 'A'
AND tableA.match = matches.match
--  before edit  AND tableA.match2 <> matches.match2 
AND tableA.match2 <> Coalesce(matches.match2, 'SomeValueThatCantOccurInMatch2') -- requested edit
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET STATUS = 'PASS'
    ;
```

Comment: What if match2= null for mode=A and match=abc12. Its should still pass ID 4 and 5 but here it won't coz we are comparing NULL to a value . Please edit. Thanks

Comment: @BhupinderSingh suppose there is a mode=A with NULL and a mode=B with NULL, should they not match since NULL==NULL isn't true?  Wrapping with Coalesce is another way to deal with NULLs, then if you want "NULL" to match "NULL", wrap both sides of the comparison and have same value to replace NULL, or if you want them not to match, have two different values.